# What word is this?

Tags: word, rebus

Can someone guess what the word is using the pictures as clues:

[image]

It is only one word

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is

> Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis

how?

> image from top to bottom, from left to right:
>
>  pneumonia
>  no
>  **ultra** goku
>  <s>miu</s> -> **micro** symbol
>  <s>cross</s> -> cross **scope**
>  pic
>  silicon
>  volcano
>  comic **con**
>  iosis

Comment: Can you explain more and also miu and cross are wrong

Comment: Sorry for very short answer, I used my phone, I'll update it soon

Comment: Shaking my head at how you got it! :-)

Comment: a few years ago a big mountain erupted in my country :( the first and the last four picture reminded me with a warning at that time, so I think I just need to find the name and just match it with the clue